# How to update hours in data field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have set of mongo document, I need to convert/update the below values like ("workedDate" : ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00Z"))

```
"workedDate" : ISODate("2020-07-01T20:03:04Z"),
"workedDate" : ISODate("2020-07-01T19:59:07Z"),
"workedDate" : ISODate("2020-06-30T14:00:00Z"),
"workedDate" : ISODate("2020-07-01T19:49:29Z")
```

I have tried the below query:

```
db.timeentrys.update(
  { },
  {    
    $set: {
      workedDate:{$dateFromParts:{
      year:{$year:"$workedDate"},
      month:{$month:"$workedDate"},
      day:{$dayOfMonth:"$workedDate"}
  }}
    }
  }
)
```

Getting the below error :

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 52,
                "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$dateFromParts' in 'workedDate.$dateFromParts' is not valid for storage."
        }
})
```

Comment: `$dateFromParts` key is an Aggregation Pipeline Operator. You cannot use it in `update` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dateFromParts` is an aggregation expression.  You can only use aggregation expressions in an update if you are using MongoDB 4.2, and provide a pipeline array as the second argument to `update` instead of an object.

**Edit**

In this use, just wrap the update object in `[]` to make it an array:

```
db.timeentrys.update(
  { },
  [{$set: {
      workedDate:{$dateFromParts:{
          year:{$year:"$workedDate"},
          month:{$month:"$workedDate"},
          day:{$dayOfMonth:"$workedDate"}
      }}
  }}]
)
```

Comment: How shall i proceed.can you give syntax.i m new to this.